# Adding a second segue screws up placement?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Hopefully images will explain this easily. I have two paths the user can take to get to the same view controller. When I attempt to connect the second path to the destination view controller, all of that view controller's stuff gets moved around. The Undo menu option gives me a clue about inherited metrics, but they don't seem to have changed, and I'm not sure what to do here. How should I connect the second one?

All three view controllers visible -- "1" and "2" will connect to the same target.

[all three VCs http://tmdesigned.com/ss1.png](http://tmdesigned.com/ss1.png)

Right after the second segue is connected

[second segue connected http://tmdesigned.com/ss2.png](http://tmdesigned.com/ss2.png)

A clue?

[a clue about what just happened http://tmdesigned.com/ss3.png](http://tmdesigned.com/ss3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently the issue was the simulated metrics. On one of my two "paths" for the user, at some point, I accidentally selected the bottom toolbar to be there instead of inferred. It didnt affect that viewcontroller's layout. But the target in question now, inferred it from that storyboard. Then, when I placed the elements on it, it somehow used that setting to calculate their placement. So when I connected the second path, it could no longer "infer" that it would have that toolbar, and it messed things up.

Anyways, the long story made short is that changing those from "inferred" has ramifications way down the line, and in this case the solution was to redo all the placement with no non-inferreds anywhere alone the line leading to it.